# Tesseract Tess4J - Native library (linux-x86-64/libtesseract.so) not found in resource path

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I'm using Tess4J and trying to call `tess4j.doOCR(myFile)` and I am getting this error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'tesseract': Native library (linux-x86-64/libtesseract.so) not found in resource path
```

*which are the following configurations I have in my system*

**OS version**:centos 6.8
**leptonica version** : leptonica-1.69
**tesseract version**: tesseract-3.00

**GhostScript Version:**

1.command: **`gs -v`**

I am getting  **GPL Ghostscript 9.16 (2015-03-30)**

2.command: **`ghostscript -v`**

I am getting  **GPL Ghostscript 8.70 (2009-07-31)**

**gcc version**:gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: libtesseract.so → Available are : tesseract-3.02.02-3.5.x86_64.rpm , tesseract-devel-3.02.02-3.5.x86_64.rpm , for CentOS6 ... See http://rpm.pbone.net/ ... `tesseract-devel` provides `/usr/lib64/libtesseract.so` .

Comment: as per your suggestion i installed `tesseract-3.02.02-3.5.x86_64.rpm` **1)after running 1st time am getting this error** `javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/sourceforge/lept4j/Pix : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class net.sourceforge.lept4j.Pix)` **2)after reloading same page am getting this error** `javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI` please Suggest...

Comment: After Installing `tesseract-3.02.02-3.5.x86_64.rpm` **1) command**  `tesseract /tess/abc.png out` getting this error `Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02.02 with Leptonica
index >= 0 && index < size_used_:Error:Assert failed:in file ../ccutil/genericvector.h, line 512
Segmentation fault
`